# Using Like in Sqlite with android for searching in encrypted data

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table (Table1) in SQLite with one column (Col1), this table has 100,000 rows that all values in Col1 are encrypted with special algortith.

I've used select sql ... like command in Android, Like this:

```
Select Col1
from Table1
where Col1 like 'A%';
```

I want to return all rows that started with 'A' letter.
But actually Cal1 is encrypted!! even if I use this:
"Select Col1 from Table1 where Col1 like '"+my_method_encryption("A")+"%';"   .. it will be wrong, becuase may the Encrypted values of 'A' letter in Col1 has different value with return value of my_method_encryption("A").

What should I do?

Actually There is another way to solve it, if I select all 100,000 rows and after that I will decrypt all 100,000 rows and then search. But this way will be so slow becuase maybe I will need to use this select ... like more than 10 times.
Thanks

Comment: May we ask why you are encrypting this column and why you need to search it?  Bringing all 100K into your app layer is not the way to go IMO.

Comment: Actually it is dictionary, it has 100,000 words with meaning (Col1 is the meaning), so I need to encrypt them. As we know dictionary has search (when edittext changed).

Comment: I still don't see the need for encryption.

Comment: try this https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/. It allows you to search into tables as they are not encrypted. It creates temporary decrypted SQLite db file when you start application and destroys it when you close it. Encrypted db file contains your data and lives as long as your application until it will be uninstalled

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Nothing personal, but questioning the user requirement does not justify unless you are an expert on cryptography.  It is a pretty common case where user notes, email and many personal details are stored in an encrypted format though the applications. Then user is given a search functionality within the application to search on the stored data.This is very common and typical use case.
The general answer to that is "Searchable Encryption Algorithm", I have not found a trusted and suitable Java API for that. Some Databases implement it.

Comment: @MGDeveloper I don't even know why I left those comments...of course there are use cased where we would want to protect user information, other than a password.

Comment: @yes have you found any solution ? I am also facing same issue?

Comment: Why you cannot encrypt your search character with the same key and then apply 'Like'

Comment: @AliAzazAlam because that would transform the whole encryption algorithm into a character-block substitution cypher. That provides about the same security level as a door lock made out of cheese and glued with toothpaste :) Seriously, for a block cypher a block size of a minimum 64 bits and with an IV is the least you can do to call it "encryption". Anything else is just "obfuscation".

Answer (score 1):

Encrypt the database file containing the plain-text column and table key. Make and link by key a separate db file for non-encrypted data.

Decrypt the file on open, making searches possible and join the other data based on the key.

Answer (score 1):

> where Col1 like '"+my_method_encryption("A")+"%';"

That won't work, it's in the purpose of encryption that you cannot tell from the encrypted text what the first character(s) of the plaintext are, otherwise encryption would be meaningless.

What you could do is move your decryption function to SQLite as an user function (https://www.sqlite.org/appfunc.html)

The use something like:

> where my_decrypt(Col1,'key') like 'A%'"

But this would be identical to what you wrote:

> Actually There is another way to solve it, if I select all 100,000 rows and after that I will decrypt all 100,000 rows and then search.

This is what SQLite will do, just that internally.

However, what you are trying to achieve seems to be conceptually wrong; namely:

- your encryption scope is a row:column
- you want to query the encrypted data based on what usually requires an external aggregate structure (an index). It's the only way to get a sub-linear search performance.

You should consider expanding your encryption scope to the whole table; for instance SQLite provides https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki which blocklevel-encrypts the whole database (database scope, block unit). You can also logically join an unencrypted db with an encrypted db; using `ATTACH` you bring both dbs into the same scope then use a normal `JOIN`, maybe even in a view, to bring the data together.

I'm not familiar with the Android ecosystem but a simple search for "android sqlite encryption extension" reveals that there is no shortage of alternatives for DB-level encryption.